# loading spinner using rxjs BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables, behaviorsubject

I created a loading spinner component for my **angular 4** app that should show during AJAX calls but I have trouble displaying it with a subscription to a **BehaviorSubject**.

This question is related to [how to show a spinner till the time data recieved from the server in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44940104/how-to-show-a-spinner-till-the-time-data-recieved-from-the-server-in-angular2) but not a duplicate (as I want to do it with a reusable component) and [Angular 2 + RxJS BehaviorSubject subscribe call not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39681303/angular-2-rxjs-behaviorsubject-subscribe-call-not-working) (Though I don't see any difference between my code and the accepted answer. Did I miss something?)

I basically followed this tutorial https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/22/angular2-using-custom-loader-spinner-as-service-in-angular-2-application/

Here's some of my code:

**app.modules.ts**

```
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {SomeComponent} from './some.component';
import {LoaderComponent} from './loader/loader.component';
import {LoaderService} from './loader/loader.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LoaderComponent,
        SomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    providers: [
        LoaderService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-loader></app-loader>
```

**loader.component.html**

```
<div class="loader" *ngIf="isLoading"></div>
```

**loader.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LoaderService} from './loader.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-loader',
    templateUrl: 'loader.component.html',
    providers: [LoaderService]
})

export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {
    isLoading: boolean;

    constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loaderService.status.subscribe((val: boolean) => {
            this.isLoading = val;
        });
    }
}
```

**loader.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {
    public status: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    display(value: boolean) {
        console.log('LoaderService.display ' + value);
        this.status.next(value);
    }
}
```

**A method in some service that does an AJAX call**

```
constructor(private http: Http, private loaderService: LoaderService) {
}

getSomeStuff(): Observable<SomeItem[]> {
    // show the loading spinner
    this.loaderService.display(true);

    const content = this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
        .map(this.extractData);

    content.subscribe(
        () => {
            // hide the loading spinner
            this.loaderService.display(false);
        }
    );

    return content;
}
```

The problem is that the loader never gets shown, because `isLoading` is never set to `true`. The console output:

```
LoaderComponent subscription false
LoaderService.display true
LoaderService.display false
```

So the subscription to the loaderService, that changes the value of `isLoading` in loader.component.ts only gets called once, when initializing the component. But as far as I understand how **BehaviorSubject** should work, it should be called, whenever `LoaderService.status` changes. Why not? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove `providers: [LoaderService]` from `LoaderComponent`.

Comment: @cartant AWESOME! that solved it! Thanks a lot! Can you submit it as an answer, so I can accept it? Also, could you maybe explain why this solved the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to this line in `LoaderComponent`:

```
providers: [LoaderService]
```

By specifying the service using a component-level provider, you are informing Angular that the component is to receive **its own instance** of the service. That's not what you want; you want to share the module-level instance.

Just remove that line from `LoaderComponent` so that a single instance of the service is used.

Comment: Thanks again! That makes total sense, as the instance I should be using is the one from the module providers.